# Nutrition & diet - what is the ideal BMI range for children between 6 and 12?

Tags: nutrition, bmi, children

The 6-12 year age group is in a latent period of growth, while children 12-18 years old experience their main period of growth. The usual BMI range is 18 to 23. But is it applicable to children who are 6 to 12 years old?

Sometimes with higher income groups I also find children with lower BMI scores - for example, 13. Sometimes children do not show any significant symptoms, or they have low haemoglobin counts in blood tests. And childhood obesity is becoming more common. So is it useful to take BMI into consideration to determine a balanced diet for a child of this age group? What BMI range should be considered as optimum for children below 12?

Comment: could you please have a look at your punctuation? Because its pretty annoying to have a lack of spaces behind your points.

Comment: @Ivo Flipse,I will take care next time.I will not write anything in hurry.

Comment: BMI has a number of fatal flaws, as noted in [my answer here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3364/1771).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BMI itself is a lousy proxy for physical fitness - just ask weightlifters - and it has to be calibrated to the physical scale of adult human beings, so I can't see how it could properly apply to small children. It's better to use the standard height/weight charts to see where a given child falls compared to other children (i.e. in terms of percentile).

**EDIT:** For example, the charts found [here](http://pediatrics.about.com/cs/growthcharts2/l/bl_growthcharts.htm), and in particular the [boys](http://pediatrics.about.com/library/growth_charts/nboystwo.htm) and [girls](http://pediatrics.about.com/library/growth_charts/ngirlstwo.htm) aged 2-20 charts.

Comment: @Madhuri Sathe: Um...if you like the answer, upvote it, please. You could also pick it as the correct answer, although you might want to give it a little longer in case someone else posts a better answer.